# Add password-protected WYSIWYG editing to HTML page

Tags: html, security, wysiwyg

I'd like to be able to grant password protected HTML editing to my flat HTML website. Of course I could install a content management system, but it seems to a sledge hammer to crack a nut.

Is there library/framework that lets me add a <script>.. to my HTML file that will handle:

1. A username and password facility
2. WYSIWYG editing with the ability to save

[CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) looks promising, but it doesn't seem to support (a) a username/password (b) an option to save what you edit!

Comment: You can't restrict anything without a backend server. If the code is on the front-end, it's accessible to anyone. Just install Wordpress.

Comment: So what I'm after is a cut-down version of Wordpress that handles only (a) password access and (b) wysiwyg editing with saving. I don't need or want a database.

Comment: But that's what a CMS **is**. The rest of it is gravy, but these two features are what makes a CMS a CMS. Really, you should look for the most lightweight simple CMS you can find, and that will be it. Googling for "lightweight CMS" gives several promising links on the first page.

Comment: Alternatively, just use a client-side WYSIWYG HTML editor (Microsoft Word?), and upload via FTP/SFTP. That'll be the "0-overhead" solution.

Comment: Do you have a PHP server? Or any CGI?

Comment: And he said he wanted username/password, Vilx. I would've suggested some WYSIWYG markdown editor + Jekyll, but no username+password access unless you count the FTP server.

Comment: Why anti database out of curiosity? Databases are perfect and (almost) needed for what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have my own dedicated server, and can install Drupal and Wordpress without problem. The latest Drupal 8 has something like a 11,000 files, I suspect I don't need 95% of them. And then I'd have to import my existing flat HTML files into the CMS. I'd much rather upload a dozen files, and add a bit of code to the pages I want to allow to be edited.

I'm also interested to see whether it can be done. CKEditor looks easy to add, and I've since discovered Laravel security, http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security

Comment: Three possible solutions: (1) https://www.cushycms.com (2) http://www.pagelime.com/ (3) http://veolay.com